# Как выйти из цикла for (python)

Tags: python

Есть цикл, он перебирает все комбинации чисел из списка (`lst2`), методом `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`.

Цель получить последовательность чисел с сумой элементов равной "длине" - `width` (200 в данном случае) и что бы в выдаче был первый из запрошенных форматов (обозначено `formats[0]`, в данном случае 50).

Код выдает:

```
(50, 150)
(50, 50, 100)
(50, 55, 95)
(50, 60, 90)
(50, 65, 85)
(50, 70, 80)
(50, 75, 75)
(50, 50, 50, 50)
```

Что полностью соответствует задаче.

Проблема в том что цикл не останавливается так как не перебрал все возможные комбинации.

Подскажите пожалуйста как я могу из него выйти сохранив при этом нужные мне значения.
Благодарю, код ниже.

```
from itertools import *

width = 200 # Длинна материала 

lst2 =  [50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, 180, 185, 190, 195] # Возможные форматы

formats = [50, 60] # Форматы которые должны быть в выдаче

lst3 = [] #Список в который записываются трушные варианты

for i in range(1, len(lst2) + 1):
    for a in combinations_with_replacement(lst2, i):
        if formats[0] in a and sum(a) == width:
            print(a)
            lst3 = lst3 + [str(a)]
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Проще всего поместить код в функцию и в нужном месте сделать `return`. Иначе придётся делать какой-то флаг и проверять его во внешнем цикле, чтобы сделать `break`, а во внутреннем цикле устанавливать этот флаг и тоже делать `break`

Comment: @CrazyElf можно пожалуйста в формате для дураков? Как это должно выглядеть? 

Попробовал сделать так:

`def sss():
    lst3 = []
    for i in range(1, len(lst2) + 1):
        for a in combinations_with_replacement(lst2, i):
            if formats[0] in a and sum(a) == width:
                print(a)
                lst3.append(a)
    print(lst3)
    return lst3
sss()`

Код виснет не выдает вообще ничего

Comment: Ну вроде всё правильно. Только ещё напечатать или куда-то присвоить можете то, что вернёт ваша функция `print(sss())`.

Comment: Судя по количеству "отступов" в комментарии, return стоит в конце функции, а не где-то внутри циклов. Так вы снова будете дожидаться полного перебора. Условие выхода то какое? Сколько вариантов надо найти? Если все, то придётся ждать до упора.

Comment: @GrAnd  к сожалению количество возможных вариантов не известно,  оно всегда разное. По этому ограничить всё длиной lst3 не выйдет.

Comment: @CrazyElf сейчас добился от этого варианта работы, но почему то он выдаёт все варианты с суммой элементов = 200 не учитывая требования выдавать только те в которых присутствует первый вариант списка необходимых форматов.

Comment: ``else: pass``  бессмысленная конструкция. Можно смело убирать.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно только первое значение, то остановиться можно так:

```
for i in range(1, len(lst2) + 1):
    for a in combinations_with_replacement(lst2, i):
        if formats[0] in a and sum(a) == width:
            lst3.append(a)
            break
    else:
        continue
    break

print(lst3)
```

Если нужно больше, то делаете первый `break` по достижению нужной `len(lst3)`.